# Is it possible to put meta-information into a file using Mercurial and if so how?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

In CVS (and RCS, I gather) the classic $...$ mechanism was used to insert meta-information into a file.  Is there a mechanism or extension for doing something similar in Mercurial (or, for curiosity, other distributed versioning software)?  I'm really only interested in tracking the date of the most recent change incorporated into the file.

Answer (score 1):

That mechanism is usually known as "RCS Keywords". The [Keyword Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordExtension), distributed with Mercurial, appears to do exactly what you want.